# Execute remote python script via SSH

Tags: python, ssh

I want to execute a Python script on several (15+) remote machine using SSH. After invoking the script/command I need to disconnect ssh session and keep the processes running in background for as long as they are required to.

I have used Paramiko and PySSH in past so have no problems using them again. Only thing I need to know is how to disconnect a ssh session in python (since normally local script would wait for each remote machine to complete processing before moving on).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This might work, or something similar:

```
ssh user@remote.host nohup python scriptname.py &
```

Basically, have a look at the [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command.

Comment: Hi! I am trying this solution but my python is not executed... How can I debug what is wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

On Linux machines, you can run the script with 'at'.

echo "python scriptname.py" ¦ at now

Comment: :). I personally found 'at' to be more versatile for me, but 'nohup' is good enough in many situations.

Comment: I've also tried this solution but my python is not executed... How can I debug what is wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to perform repetitive tasks on many hosts, like for example deploying software and running setup scripts, you should consider using something like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/)

> Fabric is a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for
>   streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems
>   administration tasks.
>
> It provides a basic suite of operations for executing local or remote
>   shell commands (normally or via sudo) and uploading/downloading files,
>   as well as auxiliary functionality such as prompting the running user
>   for input, or aborting execution.
>
> Typical use involves creating a Python module containing one or more
>   functions, then executing them via the fab command-line tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) in this scenario.

As per the **tmux** documentation:

> tmux is a terminal multiplexer. It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal. And do a lot more

From a tmux session, you can run a script, quit the terminal, log in again and check back as it keeps the session until the server restart.

[How to configure tmux on a cloud server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-tmux-on-a-cloud-server)