# Making su non-interactive

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, server-administration

I was in need of a script to perform certain actions remotely using python and paramiko. I performed sudo operations in remote machine using

> 'echo '+password+' | sudo -S '+'cmd_to_be_executed'

and tty issue was solved by setting the flag get_pty as true in paramiko. Now there is a remote machine which does not have sudo permission for that user, **only way to switch to root is by using su command**. So I tried

> 'echo '+password+' | su -c '+'cmd_to_be_executed'

but it throws tty issue. Now even if I, set pty flag as true in paramiko the same issue appears

> standard in must be a tty

Is there any way to solve this ? Any help is much appreciated thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a Python command script achieve this.

Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to accept command line arguments, which will be your password.

Use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to call your script. You may need to use the shell=True with subprocess. (Or use [Pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of subprocess).

Try something like this:

```
import subprocess, argparse

#Set up the command line arguments

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Provide root password.')
parser.add_argument('--password', help='password help')

# Collect the arguments from the command line
args = parser.parse_args()

# Open a pipe to the command you want to run
p = subprocess.Popen(['su', '-c', !!your command here!!],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Prepare the password and write it
pwd = args.password + '\n'
p.stdin.write(pwd)
p.communicate()[0]
p.stdin.close()
```

Comment: `popen()` cannot handle commands like `ssh`/`su` which read passwords from tty. that's why we have `expect`/`pexpect`.

Comment: The same error persists moreover I should use ssh to connect to the remote machine at first

Comment: Yes, you would need to have the python script running on the remote machine after you ssh onto it (take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180390/execute-remote-python-script-via-ssh)